# Migrating Data from Nexus2 to Nexus3 via Upgrade Agent

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

based on the documentation to upgrade Nexus2 to Nexus3 we can use the **Upgrade Agent** but now I am wondering is it possible to use it for data migration, my use case is, I have already Nexus3 with data inside, for the other project we are using Nexus2 which now we want to move data to Nexus3, just wondering if migrating in this way cause some configuration issue or overriding blob in Nexus3.

Does anyone tried it for migrating data from one instance to already existed instance with data inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end I had to come with this solution as I am using the Nexus OSS.

first download the target repository from Nexus 2

```
wget --user user --password pass --recursive --no-parent http://NEXUS2-URL/nexus/content/repositories/maven-releases/
```

then used this library to import them:
https://github.com/AlexLiue/nexus-repository-import-scripts, it supports NuGet, Maven, NPM

Answer (score 0):

I would check [repository import](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/tasks/repository-import), maybe that solves your problems

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin is only available with PRO license!